# Textbox RTL mixed with LTR and numbers

Tags: html

http://jsfiddle.net/53j53jtm/1/

```
<input type=text dir=ltr value="אום SS 5.56">
<input type=text dir=rtl value="אום SS 5.56">
```

I am trying to allow users to type mixed RTL and LTR languages in the same textbox.
How do I make the textbox readable while editing RTL text with mixed LTR markdown?

**Picture from Microsoft Word. How it should look like:**

[image: Picture from Microsoft Word. How it should look like]

Comment: Its very unclear what you are asking. More of what you have other than just the input boxes. Those don't tell anyone much about what you have to work with.

Comment: What markdown are you talking about? What exactly are you after? The picture shows a mixed-direction presentation of the string in the code examples, with overall right-to-left directionality that overrides the natural directionality of Latin letters between words, but not inside them. If you really want that, the user must enter appropriate directionality control characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this is not supported because CSS cannot be applied to a portion of a tag. It's all-tag or nothing.

You could have a keyup listener, store the values in-memory, parse the content and generate your own output and make it look like a single input.

Answer (score 4):

When you deal with several input formats, the best approach is to split the inputs completely. This is helpful not just to make sure your RTL/LTR separation is done well, but also for UX purposes

- Making sure your user understands what they are expected to type
- Making sure your display of the inputted result is correctly formatted (with some `<span dir='rtl'>` or `<span dir='ltr'>`)
- Making it easier for your code (whatever analyzes the form inputs) to recognize between LTR-centric/RTL-centric text and numbers (which can then help you do things like sorting and search much better)
- And as a bonus, making sure that mobile devices load the correct keyboard (the number pad vs the full keyboard)

On top of that, it seems like your case is actually a numerical input that has a trailing unit set after it. In that case, you should consider either adding the unit as a static span (if it is always the same unit) or even some drop-down choice for your users to pick. This will mean you are splitting actual numbers and "string" inputs but also the *context of what the user is expected to insert* which is usually a good UX decision.

If all your suffixes are the same, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="number" dir="ltr" placeholder="Gauge" />
<span dir="ltr" lang="en">SS</span> <span dir="rtl" lang="he">אום</span>
```

If you want to allow custom/user-inputted suffixes, you can have two inputs, using ltr-string for number+unit and another for RTL, something like this:

```
<input type="text" dir="ltr" placeholder="5.56 ss" />
<input type="text" dir="rtl" placeholder="אום" />
```

I'd recommend thinking about your UI and UX and consider what your actual user-generated content is supposed to be; it may be easier if you have preset suffixes, for example, or it may be easier to rearrange the way a user adds the data if you decide your input requires some other format. Either way, making those decisions will help you display the correct formatting **and** make it easier for your users to insert the data you expect.